# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

I'm doing Web camera App in Visual Studio 2012. When I build my program, I got this type of error.An unhandled exception of type `System.TypeInitializationException` occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

Additional information: The type initializer for `Emgu.CV.CvInvoke` threw an exception.

Error Log:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
Additional information: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x19d4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8784] CameraApp.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8784] CameraApp.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Please add error log (in text) to your question.

Comment: There is a surprisingly [helpful and detailed guide here](http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/emgu-cv-c/-emgu-cv-invoke-threw-an-exception-solution).

Comment: Check your inner exception. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11369684/345659) might help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what may be causing them, but you could set the debugger to stop at the very first first chance exception so you atleast get an idea of what may be causing the problem.

To do this go to Debug/Exceptions...

On the exceptions dialog box, click the Throw check box for the Common Language Runtime Exceptions this cause the debugger to stop immediatelly on the first change exception....and give you an idea of what is going on....

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I run my app in a 64 bit OS.  If your OS is 64 bit, that is the culprit.