# Emgu cv invoke exception c#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

i just downloaded emgucv library and installed it,followed a tutorial on youtube -added the right dll's refrences to my project but im getting an error when intializing an `emgucv image`

```
Image<Bgr,Byte> img=new Image<Bgr,Byte>(@"C:\Users\pro\Desktop\Itamar\LolTools\Autologin\Resources\Logo.png");
```

the most common exception in that library:`The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception`

i've searched for many solution over the net,to copy the dll files to 64x directory in my project,add the dlls and set `always copy` still nothing works.
im probably breaking my head about this so i would be realy happy if someone could help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369684/emgucv-typeinitializationexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your IDE is visual studio, follow this:

project -> properties -> build

and then make your platform target x64