# System.TypeInitializationException when try -> capWebcam = New Capture()

Tags: vb.net, opencv, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit, emgucv

I have an error when I try to start the webcam:
System.TypeInitializationException

When try to:

```
Dim capWebcam As Capture


 Try
            capWebcam = New Capture()   <<<<<<<here
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Text = ex.Message
            Return
        End Try
```

I have this DLL added to the project:

```
opencv -
calib3d240
contrib240
core240
features2d240
ffmpeg240_64
flann240
gpu240
highgui240
imgproc240
legacy240
ml240
nonfree240
objdetect240
photo240
stitching240
videostab240

 And ENGU:
 CV.Stitching
 CV.UI
 CV.GPU
 CV.DebuggerVIsualizers.VS2010
 CV.ML
 CV.OCR
 Util
 CV
```

I tried one hundred possibilities and nothing :(

The project has a form that the person can choose an image file or a webcam, choosing colors RGB options and will detect circles, lines and polys.
It is a Big code, but is here (EDIT -> I try to make the code smaller so I delete the code that have no changes in the webcam, if appear some IF that is not closed, maybe is because I edited it):

```
Option Strict On

Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.CvEnum
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.CV.UI


Public Class frmForm

'Variaveis

Dim capWebcam As Capture
Dim blnWebcamCapturingInProcess As Boolean = False


'Construtor 
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()        ' Metodo necessario para instanciar o Design

    intOrigFormWidth = Me.Width
    intOrigFormHeight = Me.Height
    intOrigTableLayoutPanelWidth = tlpLabelsAndImageBoxes.Width
    intOrigTableLayoutPanelHeight = tlpLabelsAndImageBoxes.Height


End Sub


' Metodos dos componentes _____

Private Sub frmForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load, MyBase.Resize


End Sub

Private Sub frmForm_Resize(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    'This If Else statement is necessary to throw out the first time the Form1_Resize event is called.
    'For some reason, in VB.NET the Resize event is called once before the constructor, then the constructor is called,
    'then the Resize event is called each time the form is resized.  The first time the Resize event is called
    '(i.e. before the constructor is called) the coordinates of the components on the form all read zero,
    'therefore we have to throw out this first call, then the constructor will run and get the correct initial
    'component location data, then every time after that we can let the Resize event run as expected
    If (blnFirstTimeInResizeEvent = True) Then
        blnFirstTimeInResizeEvent = False
    Else
        tlpLabelsAndImageBoxes.Width = Me.Width - (intOrigFormWidth - intOrigTableLayoutPanelWidth)
        tlpLabelsAndImageBoxes.Height = Me.Height - (intOrigFormHeight - intOrigTableLayoutPanelHeight)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub rdoImageFile_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoImageFile.CheckedChanged
    If (rdoImageFile.Checked = True) Then
        If (blnWebcamCapturingInProcess = True) Then
            RemoveHandler Application.Idle, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI)
            blnWebcamCapturingInProcess = False
        End If

        ibOriginal.Image = Nothing
        ibGrayColorFiltered.Image = Nothing
        ibCanny.Image = Nothing
        ibCircles.Image = Nothing
        ibLines.Image = Nothing
        ibTrisRectsPolys.Image = Nothing

        lblFile.Visible = True
        txtFile.Visible = True
        btnFile.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rdoWebCam_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoWebCam.CheckedChanged
    If (rdoWebCam.Checked = True) Then
        Try
            capWebcam = New Capture()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Text = ex.Message
            Return
        End Try

        AddHandler Application.Idle, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI)
        blnWebcamCapturingInProcess = True

        lblFile.Visible = False
        txtFile.Visible = False
        btnFile.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    If (Not capWebcam Is Nothing) Then
        capWebcam.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFile.Click
    Dim drDialogResult As DialogResult = ofdFile.ShowDialog()

    If (drDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Or drDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) Then
        txtFile.Text = ofdFile.FileName
        If (txtFile.Text <> String.Empty) Then
            ProcessImageAndUpdateGUI(New Object(), New EventArgs())
        End If
    End If
End Sub


End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: That looks like more code than strictly needed. Can you reduce the code further until [no code can be removed while still running into the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: ready, I delete the form methods :)

Comment: This is an oooold story. The `TypeInitializationException` with EmguCV has in 99.9% cases only one reason: OpenCV dlls are missing or have wrong versions. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369684/emgucv-typeinitializationexception) or [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp).